# Am I using encode correctly/incorrectly in Python 3 to convert a string into bytes?

Tags: python, string, byte, encode, pyserial

I'm a little confused about the encode and bytes functions, when I do a conversion from string to bytes, I'm getting additional bytes.

Where are the additional bytes coming from (in the conversion)?

I tried the bytes function and the encode function as explained here:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytes

`fake_serial_data = chr(176)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(73)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(255)`

`print("Number of bytes in original data:", len(fake_serial_data))`

`encoded_fake_serial_data = fake_serial_data.encode()`

`print(encoded_fake_serial_data)`

`print("Number of bytes in encoded data:", len(encoded_fake_serial_data))`

Comment: Why do you have a string object at all?

Comment: To do String to Bytes conversion, do `bytes(fake_serial_data, 'UTF-8')`. Or better yet, `struct.pack('B', 176)` etc.

Comment: Torxed, it's adding bytes. Where are they coming from?

Answer (score 0):

PySerial already works in terms of bytes. You don't need to perform any string->bytes conversion, because PySerial won't give you a string. Just keep the bytes objects that PySerial gives you.

---

In your `fake_serial_data` test, `len(fake_serial_data)` is not a number of bytes. `fake_serial_data` is not a sequence of bytes, and asking how many bytes are in it is like asking how many pixels are in your house, or how much pencil lead is in these words you're reading.

`len(fake_serial_data)` is the number of Unicode code points in `fake_serial_data`, and `len(encoded_fake_serial_data)` is the number of bytes in the UTF-8 encoding of `fake_serial_data`. There is no reason to expect a one-to-one correspondence between Unicode code points and resulting bytes. In UTF-8, code points above 127 don't map to a single byte.

---

If you want an encoding that maps Unicode code points in the 0-255 range to individual bytes (and fails on Unicode code points outside that range), there's `latin1`, but wanting such a thing usually means you're making a mistake.

Comment: Gotcha, I was working from a string object as a test of another function.

I'll remove that part from this question.